# python psycopg2 changed dateformat

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

When i select in psql this

```
select ts_changed, to_char(ts_changed, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS') 
from ...
```

i got this format.

- 2022-01-05 14:51:11.334

in a python script with psycopg i got this

- 2022-01-05 14:49:05.777000

psycopg has added three more digits i dont want, because i provides trouble with elasticsearch.
Here runs my query

```
  pg_init_connect = 'host={} dbname={} user={}'.format(db_host, db_db, db_user)
  pg_connect = psycopg2.connect(pg_init_connect)

  do_sql = pg_connect.cursor()
  do_sql.execute(db_query)
  result = do_sql.fetchall()
  pg_connect.commit()
  return(result)
```

How to say psycopg to return the right date?

Comment: Works for me - are you sure you aren't looking at the first column in the result, which would be a Python datetime?

Comment: What is the actual value for  `db_query` ?

Comment: Ok i found a solution. Simple cast the datefield from postgres to a string like this "to_char(ts_created, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS') as ts_created",  then psycopg dont make a datetimefield from the output.